# There are excess white spaces between three divs on the same row

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
            <div id="main_page">
                <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div class="d-inline-block col-md-4 cuisine_slogan">
                        <h2>Enjoy different cuisines around the world!</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-inline-block col-md-4 padding-0 pict01">
                        <img src="different_cuisines.png" alt="cuisines_picture01" width="630" height="600">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-inline-block col-md-4 padding-0 pict02">
                        <img src="different_cuisines02.png" alt="cuisines_picture02" width="600" height="600">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        margin: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    #main_page {
        padding-top:20px;
        
    }
    #main_page h2{
        float:left;
    }
    .cuisine_slogan{
        height:600px;
        background-color:greenyellow;
    }
    .cuisine_slogan h2{
        padding-top:150px;
        padding-left:30px;
        font-size:80px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .row{
        padding:0;
        
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    img{
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left:0;
    }
```

I tried to use `margin-left:0;` and  `margin-right:0;` on the img part but when I refresh the html page it still contains white spaces between images and the green box. May I ask is there a method to make the green box stick with the images without any white spaces on the row including the leftmost and rightmost?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using bootstrap, so you can add inline padding-left:0; to columns

```
  .padding-0 {
                padding-left: 0 !important;
            }
```